# Runtime error A PWM object already exists for this GPIO channel

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

iam new to raspberry pi and i got an error while a running servo motor in my object detection script

Here is the part of the code all import functions are given on top of code

```
for i in range (classes.size):
    if(classes[0][i] == 2 and scores[0][i]>0.5):

      servoPIN = 22
      GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
      GPIO.setup(servoPIN, GPIO.OUT)
      p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50)  #line 150
      p.start(2.5) # Initialization
      try:

        p.ChangeDutyCycle(5)
        time.sleep(4)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(10)
        time.sleep(4)
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.stop()
      except:
          #print ("exception")

        GPIO.cleanup()
```

output:(motor turns on and immediately showing below error)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Object_detection_picamera.py", line 150, in <module>
    p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50) # GPIO 17 for PWM with 50Hz
RuntimeError: A PWM object already exists for this GPIO channel
```

I dont know why this happening please help me

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the following is line 150? `p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50) #`

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention  and you are right

Comment: Are you sure that nothing else is already using the PWM channel, such as the on-board audio?

Comment: no nothing else is using

Comment: Were you expecting `classes[0][i] == 2 and scores[0][i]>0.5` to be true in exactly one case?  Apparently it's true more than once, resulting in multiple attempts to configure the same GPIO pin.

Comment: yeah if its true more than once the same  pin should work until the condition become false

Comment: Except that it's *explicitly telling you* that the same pin doesn't work again.  Try putting the pin setup at the top of the program (or somewhere else where it executes only once), rather than inside a loop.

Comment: i tried that but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

> p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50)  #line 150

this line should never be in a loop 
PWM channel shold be initialized only on

So simply remove that line from the loop the put it before the loop